# Counting newline characters in bash shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I cannot get this script to work at all. I am just trying to count the number of lines in a file WITHOUT using wc. here is what I have so far

```
FILE=file.txt
lines=0
while IFS= read -n1 char
do
if [ "$char" == "\n" ]
then
lines=$((lines+1))
fi
done < $FILE
```

this is just a small part of a bigger script that should count total words, characters and lines in a file. I cannot figure any of it out though. Please help

The problem is the if-statement conditional is never true.. Its as if the program cannot detect what a '\n' is.

Comment: After some testing and editing of my answer, my answer should now provide a working example :-)

Comment: your Q's title is counting "\n", but in your Q, first sentence you said want to count the number of lines. They are NOT the same. if you `echo -n "abc" > file.txt` wc and your script(corrected by nice people below) will return 0. but there is one line in file.txt. It may not be your case, but I just remind you about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare -i lines=0 words=0 chars=0
while IFS= read -r line; do
    ((lines++))
    array=($line)               # don't quote the var to enable word splitting
    ((words += ${#array[@]}))
    ((chars += ${#line} + 1))   # add 1 for the newline
done < "$filename"
echo "$lines $words $chars $filename"
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems there. They are fixed in the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
file=file.txt
lines=0
while IFS= read -rN1 char; do
if [[ "$char" == $'\n' ]]; then
    ((++lines))
fi
done < "$file"
```

One problem was the `$'\n'` in the test, the other one, more subtle, was that you need to use the `-N` switch, not the `-n` one in read (`help read` for more information). Oh, and you also want to use the `-r` option (check with and without, when you have backslashes in your file).

Minor things I changed: Use more robust `[[...]]`, used lower case variable names (it's considered bad practice to have upper case variable names). Used arithmetic `((++lines))` instead of the silly `lines=$((lines+1))`.